# Execute a block based on the output of a variable

Tags: shell-script, function, for, oracle

Below is the script i drafted, that will work based on the SIDs it will get from

```
 ps -ef | grep pmon
```

Once the SID is grepped, it will pass the SID to `dbenv()` to set the necessary parameters, and it also cuts the DB_VERSION from `/etc/oratab` entries.

Based on the version, if 12 or 11 then the script should execute a block, or if the version is 10 or 9, it should execute a block.

12 or 11 has the alert logs under `TRACE_FILE`'s value, 10 or 9 wont have any output for `TRACE_FILE`, so 10 and 9 should clear the alert log based on `BDUMP`s value.

So I have drafted the below script and it works fine, I feel the script has got lot of repetition where i applied logic for DB_VERSION.

Any ideas on how could this script be enhanced

```
#############################################################################################################################################################
#!/bin/bash
#############################################################################################################################################################

TODAY=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
DATE=`date +%Y%b%d`
YESTERDAY=`date -d '-1 day' +%b%Y`
YDAY=`date -d '-1 day' +%Y%b%d`
HOST=`hostname`
LOG_LOCATION="/home/oracle/utility_script/dba_maint/logs"

mkdir -p ${LOG_LOCATION}

LOG_FILE="${LOG_LOCATION}/oracle_files_cleanup_${DATE}.log"

rm ${LOG_FILE} 2>/dev/null

dbenv ()
{
        ORACLE_HOME=`cat /etc/oratab | grep ^$ORACLE_SID | cut -d":" -f2`; export ORACLE_HOME
        PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH ; export PATH
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib ; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        DB_VERSION=`cat /etc/oratab | grep "^$ORACLE_SID" | cut -d":" -f2 | rev | cut -d"/" -f2| rev | cut -d"." -f1`; export DB_VERSION
}


dbcheck()
{
        sqlplus / as sysdba << EOF &>${LOG_LOCATION}/dbcheck.out
        exit
EOF
}

sql_plus()
{
        sqlplus -s / as sysdba << EOF &>/dev/null
        SET NEWPAGE NONE;
        set lines 200 pages 300;
        set feedback off;
        set heading off;
        spool ${LOG_LOCATION}/$1.log
        $2
        exit
EOF
}

for SID in `ps -eaf | grep pmon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $8}' | sort | cut -d"_" -f3`
do
        ORACLE_SID=${SID} ; export ORACLE_SID
        dbenv ${ORACLE_SID}                                                     #-- Passing the ORACLE_SID to dbenv function to source the database.
        if [ ${DB_VERSION} -eq 11 -o ${DB_VERSION} -eq 12 ]
        then
                dbcheck
                DB_CHECK=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/dbcheck.out | egrep "ORA|SP2|idle"`
                LOWER_SID=`echo ${ORACLE_SID} | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`

#-- Queries to fetch the proper log location from database

                ADUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='audit_file_dest';"
                BDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='background_dump_dest';"
                CDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='core_dump_dest';"
                UDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='user_dump_dest';"
                TRACE_FILE="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='diagnostic_dest';"

#-- Calls the sql_plus function with the parameters as the logname and SQL query

                sql_plus "adump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${ADUMP}"
                sql_plus "bdump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${BDUMP}"
                sql_plus "cdump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${CDUMP}"
                sql_plus "udump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${UDUMP}"
                sql_plus "trace_${ORACLE_SID}" "${TRACE_FILE}"

#-- Remove any empty lines after the log location

                ADUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/adump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                BDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/bdump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                CDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/cdump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                UDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/udump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                TRACE_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/trace_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`

#-- If the Database is not in idle state or without any errors, start housekeeping

                if [ -z "${DB_CHECK}" ]
                then
                        echo -e "\t\t\t\t HOUSEKEEPING for database : ${ORACLE_SID}" >>${LOG_FILE}
                        echo -e "\t\t\t\t ============ === ======== = =============" >>${LOG_FILE}

#-- Cleans .aud files older than 60 days in ADUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${ADUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\t\t\tAdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in BDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${BDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\n\t\t\tBdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in CDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${CDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tCdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in UDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${UDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tUdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Rotates the Database alert log on 01st of every month.

                        if [ `date +%d` -eq 01 ]
                        then
                                if [ ! -z "${TRACE_LOC}" ]
                                then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tALERT LOG ROTATION" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                                fi
                        fi

#-- Rotates the Listener log on 01st of every month.

                        if [ `date +%d` -eq 01 ]
                                        if [ ! -z "${TRACE_LOC}" ]
                                        then
                                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tLISTENER LOG ROTATION" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                                        fi
                        fi
                else
                        echo -e "ERROR : Please fix the below error in database - ${ORACLE_SID} on host - ${HOST} \n ${DB_CHECK}" >> ${LOG_LOCATION}/house_keeping_fail_${ORACLE_SID}_${DATE}.log
                fi
        elif [ ${DB_VERSION} -eq 10 -o ${DB_VERSION} -eq 9 ]
        then
                dbcheck
                DB_CHECK=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/dbcheck.out | egrep "ORA|SP2|idle"`

#-- Queries to fetch the proper log location from database

                ADUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='audit_file_dest';"
                BDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='background_dump_dest';"
                CDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='core_dump_dest';"
                UDUMP="select DISPLAY_VALUE from v\$parameter where name='user_dump_dest';"

#-- Calls the sql_plus function with the parameters as the logname and SQL query

                sql_plus "adump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${ADUMP}"
                sql_plus "bdump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${BDUMP}"
                sql_plus "cdump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${CDUMP}"
                sql_plus "udump_${ORACLE_SID}" "${UDUMP}"

#-- Remove any empty lines after the log location

                ADUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/adump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                BDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/bdump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                CDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/cdump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`
                UDUMP_LOC=`cat ${LOG_LOCATION}/udump_${ORACLE_SID}.log | sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'`

#-- If the Database is not in idle state or without any errors, start housekeeping

                if [ -z "${DB_CHECK}" ]
                then
#-- Cleans .aud files older than 60 days in ADUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${ADUMP_LOC}" ]
                                        echo -e "\t\t\tAdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in BDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${BDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\n\t\t\tBdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in CDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${CDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tCdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Cleans .trm or .trc files older than 60 days in UDUMP location

                        if [ ! -z "${UDUMP_LOC}" ]
                        then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tUdump cleanup" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                        fi

#-- Rotates the ${DB_VERSION} version Database alert log on 01st of every month.

                        if [ `date +%d` -eq 01 ]
                        then
                                if [ ! -z "${BDUMP_LOC}" ]
                                then
                                        echo -e "\n\t\t\tALERT LOG ROTATION" >> ${LOG_FILE}
                                fi
                        fi
               else
                       echo -e "ERROR : Please fix the below error in database - ${ORACLE_SID} on host - ${HOST} \n ${DB_CHECK}" >> ${LOG_LOCATION}/house_keeping_fail_${ORACLE_SID}_${DATE}.log
               fi
        fi
done
exit $?
#---------------------------------------------------------------------END-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a general code review rather than a specific answerable question.  Stack Exchange has a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site for asking this kind of question.

Comment: that said, here's some general advice: 1. use `$()` rather than backticks for command substitution.  2. you (almost) never need to pipe grep in to awk.  e.g.  instead of `ps -eaf | grep pmon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $8}'`, you can do `ps -eaf | awl '/pmon/ && ! /grep/ {print $8}'`.  3. you don't need to do that anyway, you can just do `ps h -o cmd -C pmon` instead.  4. `sed` can read files by itself, you don't need to pipe `cat `into `sed`. 5.   `[ -n "$var" ]` is the same as `[ ! -z "$var" ]`.  `-z` tests for empty string, `-n` tests for non-empty string.

Comment: @cas I consider your advice, I will make changes accordingly. And I don't think this comes under code review. I have a doubt of how to use if statements more efficiently, instead of repeating the code in script. I don't know how to do that efficiently.

Comment: The `#!`-line has to be the very first line in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question probably belongs on 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of here, but here are my recommendations:

1. use `$()` rather than backticks for command substitution.
2. you (almost) never need to pipe `grep` in to `awk`.  For example, instead of:

   ```
   ps -eaf | grep pmon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $8}'
   ```

   you can do:

   ```
   ps -eaf | awk '/pmon/ && ! /grep/ {print $8}'
   ```

   Similarly, piping `grep` into `cut` is usually better done with `awk`.  e.g instead of:

   ```
   cat /etc/oratab | grep ^$ORACLE_SID | cut -d":" -f2
   ```

   use

   ```
   awk -F: "/^$ORACLE_SID/ {print \$2}" /etc/oratab
   ```

   (normally you wouldn't escape the `$` of `$2` in an `awk` script because it's more usual to single-quote the entire `awk` script.  In this case, we're double-quoting the `awk` script so that we can use the bash variable `$ORACLE_SID` in `awk`, so we need to backslash-escape `awk`'s `$2` to prevent the shell from replacing it with its own `$2`)
3. you don't need to do pipe `ps` into `grep` or `awk` anyway. You can just do `ps h -o cmd -C pmon` instead.  Or use `pgrep`.
4. `sed` can read files by itself, you don't need to pipe `cat`into `sed`.  So can `grep` and `awk` and `perl` and `cut` and every other standard text-processing tool.
5. `[ -n "$var" ]` is the same as `[ ! -z "$var" ]`.

   `-z` tests for empty string, `-n` tests for non-empty string.
6. there are several occasions where you haven't double-quoted your variables.  you should (almost) always double-quote variables when you use them.
7. single-quotes are for fixed, literal strings.  double-quotes are for when you want to interpolate a variable or command substitution into a string.
8. indenting with 8 characters is excessive.  use 2 or 4 spaces per indent level.  or set the tab stop in your editor to 2 or 4 spaces.
9. it's a good habit to use lowercase or MixedCase for your own variables, leaving ALLCAPS variable names for standard utilities and common programs.
10. tools like `sqlplus`, `mysql`, `psql`, etc are very convenient for doing scripted database queries in sh or bash etc but you have to be extremely careful about any variables you use with SQL commands - especially if the values in the variables come from user-supplied data, or other "untrusted" sources.  It is very easy to break a script if the input data is unvalidated and unsanitised.  It is just as easy to create an SQL injection bug.

    For non-trivial SQL queries, you should probably learn `perl` or `python` or some other language with a database library that supports placeholders to avoid any issues with quoting of variables in sql commands.